# How to know which topological invariant is in play?

Tags: condensed-matter, topology, topological-insulators, chern-simons-theory

I'm currently working on the Haldane model where I've worked through the math to find that when the condition

$$
\frac{M}{t_2} = 3 \sqrt{3} sin (\phi)
$$

is satisfied the gap closes, meaning there is a change of topological properties. I know for a fact that the topological invariant in question is the Chern number, but I question why is it the Chern number and not de 2D Zak phase. (I also don't understand the difference between the two, which might be the reason of my question).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is 2d Zak phase? I have only seen Zak phase associated with 1d systems.

Comment: @d_b The 2D Zak phase, from what I've seen is the topological invariant related to weak topological insulators and the difference between the 1D and 2D version is just the integral where in the latter you use a double integral for both $ k_x $ and $ k_y $ in the first Brillouin zone.

Answer (score 0):

A topological invariant, strictly speaking, is not a meaningful concept for one isolated model. It is rather only meaningful for a *family* of models, where one clearly defines the boundaries of the family.

Example: One can consider for example the SSH model as a specimen in the family of time-reversal *and* chiral invariant 1D models, in which case the appropriate invariant is $\mathbb{Z}_2$ valued. However one may also consider the very same model as belonging to the wider family of merely chiral invariant 1D models, in which case the appropriate invariant is $\mathbb{Z}$ valued.

The Haldane model is usually considered as belonging to the family of 2D insulators with *no* additional symmetries, in which case the *strong* invariant is the Chern number. I have not previously heard of the 2D זעק (Zak) phase being associated with weak invariants in 2D but I guess it's possible?

Comment: First I would like to thank for your thorough response! As of now I understand that the question made does not really make a whole lot of sense, since I didn't really understood the concept around topological invariants.